# Image to be max-width: 100%, height: auto but height not less than XX without scretching

Tags: html, css, image

There is an image inside a container. Image takes 100% of its width and height is auto. But I want to set the height to be at least XXX pixels so when I resize container's width, no matter what, the image stays at least certain height and width increases in order to keep proportions. The problem with my current approach below is that image dimensions get skewed after container is resized.

```
<div class="imageHelper">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7230/7218149614_e0ba252f73_b.jpg" alt="image" />
</div>

.imageHelper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imageHelper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:auto\9;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 600px;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I have setup Fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/5JY8c/1/ ) which you can try to resize and check out why current approach is not working.

Comment: It would be nice if CSS had a "proportions: fixed" thing. It would be helpful for iframes and stuff.

Comment: You can't have a max width and min height and maintain the aspect ratio. They're conflicting requirements. If you shrink the window so it's 50px wide, then the image has to be at most 50px wide to satisfy the max-width propery, and be at least 600px tall to meet the min-height requirement. It'll be stretched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This article might help in general:

http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/control-image-aspect-ratios-css3-2122968

And this part in particular:

> ```
> object-fit: cover;
> overflow: hidden;
> ```

Works with CSS3.

UPD:
As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65387/mark) suggested, this approach only works in modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/object-fit

Comment: Didn't know about this CSS property. The compatibility on it is is practically non-existent, however: http://caniuse.com/object-fit

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
.imageHelper img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9R6zp/)

You can change both the height and width of the container.. and the image will always remain proportional.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to relay on `line-height` and `text-align` to center your image. Then , using negative margin , you can virtually reduce size of image, at least space that image needs.

if you want image to be width:100% and min-height:600px, it is not coherent and you need to cut something so it keeps its ratio but with some parts hidden .vertical or horizontal.

This in the case your image is part of your content, else , **if it is only decoration**, a `background-image` `-position` & `-size` should do.
Example with clipping a single image in the flow from its center : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/fdIxe

```
.imageHelper {
  height: 600px;
  line-height: 600px;/*set baseline right in vertical middle */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;/* center image or texte */
}
.imageHelper img {
  margin: -100%;/* reduce virtually to 0 space used by image so it follows from center,  line-height and text-align set in parent  :) */
  vertical-align:middle;/* stands on baseline */
/* keep both height/width flexible */
  min-height:600px;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

since this is using basic CSS , compatibility with older browser should be increased :)